# Getting stale exception in selenium while looping through web elements

Tags: python, selenium

## while looping through the web elements which is pushed to an list, getting exception called stale exception as there is no DOM present while looping back to the page.

Below is the code that i have tried to use, but not getting the work done.

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="wpbody-content"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a').click()

# To get the list of web elements
links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('row-title')


  for i in range(len(links)):
        attempt = 0
        result = False
    
        # attempting to get the DOM using a while loop (looping back to the previous page)
        while attempt < 2:
            try:
                links[i].click()
                result = True
                break
            except:
                print("stale occured")
            finally:
                attempt += 1
    
        # If found the DOM continue the execution
        if result == True:
            select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('pagegoals'))
            select.select_by_value('goal4')
    
            select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('pagetype'))
            select.select_by_value('marketing')
            
            # To execute the script
            driver.execute_script('''
                window.document.querySelector("#publish").click();
            ''')
    
            # Getting back to the previous page
            driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Comment: This exception occurs when the DOM changes between the time when you first found the element and the time when you try to perform some action on the element. You will have to find the element just before performing action.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When use the page back.the page is getting refreshed and selenium couldn't identify the element and throwing stale error.

You need re-assign the element again. try now.

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="wpbody-content"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a').click()

# To get the list of web elements
links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('row-title')


for i in range(len(links)):
        attempt = 0
        result = False
        #re-assinge the elements again
        links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('row-title')
        # attempting to get the DOM using a while loop (looping back to the previous page)
        while attempt < 2:
            try:
                links[i].click()
                result = True
                break
            except:
                print("stale occured")
            finally:
                attempt += 1

        # If found the DOM continue the execution
        if result == True:
            select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('pagegoals'))
            select.select_by_value('goal4')

            select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('pagetype'))
            select.select_by_value('marketing')

            # To execute the script
            driver.execute_script('''
                window.document.querySelector("#publish").click();
            ''')

            # Getting back to the previous page
            driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Comment: It worked,  Thank you.
But when i'm reassigning the elements, the list is created every time it is looping through. Doesn't it increase the computation time?